# Cross browser testing using TestNG

Tags: java, xml, selenium, cross-browser

My Code is

```
@BeforeTest  
@Parameters("browser")
public void browserinitialization(String browser) throws Exception
{
    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie"))
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\ESCLIPSE\\TestNG_project\\lib\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
    }
    else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\ESCLIPSE\\TestNG_project\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");
    }
    driver.get(url);             
}

@Test
public void login() throws InterruptedException
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserName")).sendKeys("name");
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnOk")).click(); 
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}

@AfterTest
public void quit()
{
    driver.quit();
}
```

My XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestSuite" thread-count="2"  parallel="tests" >
  <test name="ChromeTest">
  <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />
    <classes>
       <class name="firstreport.Firsttryfor">
     </class>
    </classes>
   </test>
  <test name="IETest">
  <parameter name="browser" value="IE" />
    <classes>
      <class name="firstreport.Firsttryfor">
      </class>
    </classes>
 </test>
```

I got the error as :

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest browserinitialization
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'browser' is required by @Configuration on method browserinitialization but has not been marked @Optional or defined
in C:\Users\arunkumars\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--441013644\testng-customsuite.xml
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:155)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:358)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createConfigurationParameters(Parameters.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:199)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:641)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:609)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest quit
SKIPPED: login

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================
```

Kindly help me out this.I am new to Java coding.Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check you have placed the xml file in correct location. This error will occur when you dont have the xml file

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vignesh. I have added the xml in my project.if it is wrong,where should I add the XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the XML file in the correct path. If you're using eclipse, you should see the xml file along with the class files.

You haven't closed the suite `</suite>`

And also, are you trying to run the class `firstreport.Firsttryfor` instead of your XML file? If so you ll get that error.